# Validation Error Messages for belongs_to Assocations made easy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have quite some belongs_to associations in my application, some of them are optional (i.e. the association could be nil), some are mandatory (association must be a valid parent record.

My initial approach was to validate the given id using my own validation method (here for a mandatory association)

```
belongs_to :category

validates :category_id, 
  presence: true

validate given_category_exists

def given_category_exists
  if category_id.present?
    errors.add( :category_id, 'must be present' ) \
      Category.exists?( category_id )
  end
end
```

Then I found out that Rails would do this for me if I would use the presence check on the association so I could omit my own validation method:

```
belongs_to :category

validates :category,
  presence: true
```

But now, the generated error message would simply state: `Category can't be blank`. The problems here are: (1) Can I provide a more useful message? (2) How can I insert my own translation for the attribute? `Category` is the default label generated from the validates method, `can't be blank` is the default error text for :blank.

Another problem with this: The related input field in the form is not marked as 'field_with_errors' as this field is identified with the attribute's name, not the association's name.

Using the standard way of doing things, I would add an additional attribute to my I18n translation file for the name of the association `category` and adding a replacement for the standard message:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      attributes:
        my_model:
          category_id: 'This Category'
          category:    'This Category'

    errors:
      models:
        my_model:
          attributes:
            category:
              blank:  'must be specified.'
```

Lots of lines where things can go wrong. And I did not like the idea to add superficial attributes which are actually not attributes but names of associations.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: No you probably use the simplest method to prevent later trouble.

Answer (score 9):

The post is old but I will still write my solution. Rails 5 has a `required` error key that you can use to cover validation messages for those belongs to associations:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Note that you don't actually need to specify a validation rule here (`validates :category, presence: true`). In order to customize your message, just use the `required` key:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        my_model:
          attributes:
            category:
              required: "The category must be specified."
```

Comment: How do you get around the issue that this will print "Category The category must be specified" as an error message because Rails prepends the name of the attribute to the message?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek you may use [error message interpolation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation) like this `required: "The %{attribute} must be specified."` and defined attribute as `en.activerecord.attributes.my_model.category = "Category"`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was overriding the errors.add method which proved to be quite simple and very efficient. A Rails association contains all information needed, I just need to pick it up there. And I could even format my own error message using a reference to the class_name of the association! Now my error message looks like this:

```
This Category must be one of the existing Categories.
```

1. Add a new standard error message:

   ```
   en:
     messages:
       blank_assoc: 'must be one of the existing %{assoc}'
   ```
2. Add the following file into the app/models/concerns folder

   ```
   module ActiveModelErrorsAdd
     def add( attribute, message = :invalid, options = {})
           if attribute != :base # that's the only other attribute I am using
         all_assocs = @base.class.reflect_on_all_associations( :belongs_to )
         this_assoc = nil
         all_assocs.each do |a|
           if a.name == attribute
             this_assoc = a
             break
           end
         end
       end
       if this_assoc.nil? # just use the standard
         super
       elsif message == :blank # replace with my own
         super( this_assoc.foreign_key, :blank_assoc,
           options.merge( assoc: this_assoc.klass.model_name.human ))
       else # use standard message but refer to the foreign_key!
         super( this_assoc.foreign_key, message, options )
       end
     end
   end

   class ActiveModel::Errors
     prepend ActiveModelErrorsAdd
   end
   ```
3. Include this file into models where needed and you will have nice error messages for all your belongs_to associations. Enjoy!

Note: This method also causes the correct input field to be marked as 'field_with_errors' - even if it has a non-standard foreign-key!