# Can't call destroy_all for ActiveRecord if validates_associated is defined for relation in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, has-many, destroy

I've defined two models and added the validation of presence one device per car (we need to keep `has_many` devices for future requirements):

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car, validate: true
  validates_associated :vehicle, message: I18n.t('devices.messages.one_device_per_car')
...
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :devices, dependent: :nullify
  validates :devices, length: { maximum: 1,
                                 too_long: I18n.t('devices.messages.one_device_per_car') }
```

I need a correct handling device validation.

When I call `car.devices.exists? # => true`

But when I try to remove all devices `car.devices.destroy_all # => []`

Only delete all works fine `car.devices.delete_all # => [...]`

So, is there a way to fix `destroy_all` method?

Comment: destroy_all instantiates each object and executes each call back, not sure what you mean by "fix" destroy_all. Sounds like it is working as documented.

Comment: You have not actually described what is failing here. Additionally `validates_associated :vehicle` has no context whatsoever in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by adding validation:

```rb
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  # Now it supports only one device per car
  validates :car_id, uniqueness: { allow_nil: true,
                                   message: I18n.t('devices.messages.one_device_per_car') }
```

and migration

```rb
class AddUniqIndexCarIdToDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    safety_assured do
      add_index :devices, :car_id, unique: true
    end
  end
```

Comment: `belongs_to` is validated by default and you can set a custom error message as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793180/1978251)